# order() function strange behavior

Tags: r

I encountered some strange behavior with the `order()` function.
It was 2 datasets (training and testing), from this code:

```
train.part <- 0.25
train.ind <- sample.int(n=nrow(newdata), size=floor(train.part*nrow(newdata)), replace=FALSE)
train.set <- newdata[train.ind,]
test.set <- newdata[-train.ind,]
```

When I try to order `train.set` by:

```
train.set <- newdata[train.ind,]
```

It's all right, but with the second dataset, it's not good:
before sorting:

```
> test.set
     noise.Y noise.Rec
1   7.226370  86.23327
2   3.965446  85.24321
3   5.896981  84.70086
4   4.101038  85.51946
5   7.965455  85.46091
6   8.329555  86.83667
8   6.579297  85.59717
9   7.392187  85.51699
10  5.878640  86.95244
...
```

after sorting:

```
    > test.set<-test.set[order(noise.Y),]
    > test.set
            noise.Y noise.Rec
    2      3.965446  85.24321
    4      4.101038  85.51946
    11     7.109978  87.44713
 ...
    NA           NA        NA
    NA.1         NA        NA
    50    17.009351  92.36286
    NA.2         NA        NA
    48    15.452493  92.09277
    53    16.514639  91.57661
    NA.3         NA        NA
...
```

It was not properly sorting and lot of unexpected NA's.

What's the reason? Thanks!

Comment: Don't you mean `order(test.set$noise.Y)`?

Comment: No, it's matched:
> length(test.set$noise.Y);length(test.set$noise.Rec)
[1] 40
[1] 40

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3250126) example?

Comment: @RuiBarradas: Oh, yeah! Thanks! It's try to sort second dataset by variable from another. Now it;s good.

Answer (score 0):

Works with me.

```
test.set <- test.set[order(test.set$noise.Y),]
    noise.Y noise.Rec
2  3.965446  85.24321
4  4.101038  85.51946
10 5.878640  86.95244
3  5.896981  84.70086
8  6.579297  85.59717
1  7.226370  86.23327
9  7.392187  85.51699
5  7.965455  85.46091
6  8.329555  86.83667
```

Note that if you want the `rownames` to be consecutive after sorting you can simply do

```
row.names(test.set) <- NULL
```